# WSO2IS facebook issues

Tags: facebook, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im currently researching of SSO implementation possibilities, which products use etc. Currently im looking to WSO2IS and to get some understanding how things are working i tried to launch sample app with facebook authentication.

WSO version 5.3

from here:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Logging+in+to+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials

than i found topic that facebook authenticator must be updated,
/**  cant post yet links due to SO rules **/

i downloaded it from here
/**  cant post yet links due to SO rules **/

deleted old and copied file 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook-5.1.4.jar
into folder repository\components\dropins and restarted server

but im still getting errors

[2017-05-29 18:11:08,245] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator} - Failed to process Facebook Connect response. org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.getToken(FacebookAuthenticator.java:269) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(FacebookAuthenticator.java:210) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:69) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:466) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:440) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:144) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:175) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:127) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:142) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53) org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:43) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:76) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72) org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91) org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the version of your org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook-5.1.3.jar

For 5.1.5.

Clone repository https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-facebook

Compile: mvn clean install

Remove old jar and add new jar.

Folder: WSO2_IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins